# Angular 6 template does not see changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular 6 component receives a big list via Input() `allItems` parameter:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
}

ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.allItems && changes.allItems.currentValue.length) {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

I wanted to show spinner while this list is loading.

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
```

However in certain cases the spinner spins forever, and the only way to stop it is to use setTimeout. Is there more elegant way of doing it? Please advise.

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.allItems && changes.allItems.currentValue.length) {
        setTimeout(() => this.isLoading = false, 0);
    }
}
```

I have tried different things: calling detectChanges of ChangeDetectorRef, applying strategy onPush, etc.

Unfortunately, the only thing that works so far is setTimeout :(

Comment: You have to provide a full example. The only thing I can guess is that `ngOnChanges` is not triggered when you add items to `allItems`. But the timeout shouldn't help in the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work without the `setTimeout`. I would probably do something like this:

```
isLoading: boolean = true;

ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ) {
    if ( this.isLoading && changes?.allItems?.currentValue?.length ) {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you so very much. I forgot that ngOnChanges fires before ngOnInit

Comment: Glad I could help, that has definitely happened to all of us at some point!

Answer (score 2):

With the following approach you can avoid using the ngOnChanges hook:

```
  @Input() set items(items: any[]) {
    this.allItems = items;
    if(this.allItems) {
     this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

And if you declare isLoading initially you can even get rid of the ngOnInit hook:

```
isLoading = false;
```